# Tkinter setting scroll bars are not working well

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTGL6.png)I have an issue to set my scroll bars in my window - seems like it there i face with two issues -

1. scroll bars are not valid
2. make the scroll bar scrollable using the mouse wheel and not just by pressing the scroll bar buttons

this is the code how i configured the scroll bars :

```
   tab_control = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(root, name = 'tabControlNotebook')

    for block in proj.sfr.blocks:
        # Iterate over sfr blocks and create tabs for them
        tab_names_dict[block.name.upper()] = tkinter.ttk.Frame(tab_control, name = block.name.lower()+"_Tab")
        tab_control.add(tab_names_dict[block.name.upper()], text=block.name.upper())
    # Create tab for TEEA\TM
    tab_names_dict['TM/TEEA'] = tkinter.ttk.Frame(tab_control, name = "tm/teea_Tab")
    tab_control.add(tab_names_dict['TM/TEEA'], text="TM/TEEA")
    tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both') # changed from grid() to pack()
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # changed row 1 to 0
    root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # Create Frame in every tab
    for block_name in tab_names_dict:
        parent_tab = tab_names_dict[block_name]
        frames_in_tabs_dict[block_name] = tkinter.ttk.Frame(parent_tab, name=block_name.lower()+"_Frame_In_Tab")




    # Each Tab contains:
    # 2 scrollbar Ver. & Hor. and Frame
    # the second Canvas contains : Registers frame & fields frame and buttons frame

    for tab_name in tab_control.children:
        block_name = tab_name.replace("_Tab", "").upper()
        widget_name = tab_name.replace("_Tab", "_Canvas_Tables")
        parent_frame = frames_in_tabs_dict[block_name]
        canvas_names_dict[block_name] = Canvas(parent_frame, name = widget_name)

    # Now we create scroll bars in the TabFrames
    for block_name in canvas_names_dict:
        ver_widget_name = block_name.lower() + "_VerScrBar"
        hor_widget_name = block_name.lower() + "_HorScrBar"
        parent_tab_widget = tab_names_dict[block_name]
        canvas_widget = canvas_names_dict[block_name]

        # The Tab is the parent frame, and the canvas inside the tab is the scroll object
        ver_sb_dict[block_name] = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(parent_tab_widget, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas_widget.yview, name=ver_widget_name)
        hor_sb_dict[block_name] = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(parent_tab_widget, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas_widget.xview, name=hor_widget_name)
        ver_sb_dict[block_name].pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        hor_sb_dict[block_name].pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        canvas_widget.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        # Configure The Canvas
        canvas_widget.configure(yscrollcommand=ver_sb_dict[block_name].set)
        canvas_widget.configure(xscrollcommand=hor_sb_dict[block_name].set)
        frames_in_tabs_dict[block_name].bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas_widget.configure(scrollregion=canvas_widget.bbox("all")))
        frames_in_tabs_dict[block_name].pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
```

my goal is to make the scroll bar valid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTGL6.png)

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: You need to update the *scrollregion* of the canvas.

Comment: Hi what do you mean by update scrollregion of the canvas?
frames_in_tabs_dict[block_name].bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas_widget.configure(scrollregion=canvas_widget.bbox("all")))
is not enough?

Comment: `frames_in_tabs_dict[block_name]` is the parent of the canvas, so why do you update the *scrollregion* of the canvas when it is resized?  You need to update the *scrollregion* of the canvas when there are new canvas items are added into the canvas..

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, could you please example your meaning? im not sure I got it.

Comment: @acw1668 could you please explane your meaning? thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what *scrollregion* is? It is the bounding area in the canvas that you want to move around (scrolling), so it is basically the minimum bounding box that includes/surrounds all the items in the canvas.