# tkinter scrollbar shows but not valid, dose anyone know what's the reason?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

Im really need help here, I think i tried everything from previous questions but still my scrollbar is not working and I dont understand why.

working with Tkinter notebook also. attach my script bellow

```
[![import tkinter.ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import *

root = Tk()
New_Tab = Toplevel(root)
tab_control = tkinter.ttk.Notebook(New_Tab)
Tab = tkinter.ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(Tab, text='TAB1')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both') # changed from grid() to pack()
New_Tab.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # changed row 1 to 0
New_Tab.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frames_in_tabs = tkinter.ttk.Frame(Tab)
parent_frame = frames_in_tabs
canvas_names = Canvas(parent_frame)
ver_widget_name = "_VerScrBar"
hor_widget_name = "_HorScrBar"
ver_sb = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(Tab, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas_names.yview, name=ver_widget_name)
hor_sb = tkinter.ttk.Scrollbar(Tab, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas_names.xview, name=hor_widget_name)
ver_sb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
hor_sb.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
canvas_names.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas_names.configure(yscrollcommand=ver_sb.set)
canvas_names.configure(xscrollcommand=hor_sb.set)
frames_in_tabs.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas_names.configure(scrollregion=canvas_names.bbox("all")))
frames_in_tabs.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
regs_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(canvas_names)
fields_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(canvas_names)
commands_frame = tkinter.ttk.Label(canvas_names)
info_frame = tkinter.ttk.LabelFrame(canvas_names)
commands_frame.pack(side=LEFT,fill='y')
regs_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
fields_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
info_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True,fill=X)
for i in range(99):
    B = tkinter.Button(regs_frame, text =f'Hello_{i}')
    C = tkinter.Button(fields_frame, text =f'Hello_{i}')
    B.pack()
    C.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Your posted code has wrong indentation, better fix it.  Also you have asked similar question ["Tkinter setting scroll bars are not working well"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76362975/tkinter-setting-scroll-bars-are-not-working-well)

Comment: indentation fixed, Yes I have similar question but last time did't got answer which help me to solve my issue. this time I give more details from my code mybe it will give more information and help other to find what Im missing.

Comment: There are missing parts in your code.  It is better to provide a [mre] which may contain only one tab in the notebook.

Comment: Hi again, I did as you ask - Minimal reproducible example. hope now it will be more clear to understand. @acw1668

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `.pack()` to put the four frames into a `Canvas` object.  You need to create another frame for the four frames and use `Canvas.create_window()` to put the frame into the canvas.  Also you need to bind a callback on the event `<Configure>` to that frame and update `scrollregion` of the canvas inside the callback:

```py
# a frame to hold the four frames
internal_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(canvas_names)
canvas_names.create_window(0, 0, window=internal_frame, anchor="nw")
# update canvas scrollregion whenever the frame is resized
internal_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas_names.config(scrollregion=canvas_names.bbox("all")))
# put the four frames into internal_frame
regs_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(internal_frame)
fields_frame = tkinter.ttk.Frame(internal_frame)
commands_frame = tkinter.ttk.Label(internal_frame)
info_frame = tkinter.ttk.LabelFrame(internal_frame)
commands_frame.pack(side=LEFT,fill='y')
regs_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
fields_frame.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
info_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True,fill=X)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it works well after using your advice.  but this time - need to  stretch  the internal_frame you created more.  its seems like its not cover all my window any idea why?

Comment: seems like it is due to create_window fucntion. could be?